# how to print a restaurant ticket to a file in C?

Tags: c, file-io, printing

My english it's very basic. I speak spanish. Please excuse me for my mistakes.
This is a restaurant simulation.

I need a way to save the total bill. The filename will be the date in the format `"%d%m%y_%H%M"` and with the file extension `*.tck`

I made an array from where I take the price:

```
float desayunoa[6] = {40.50, 40.50, 45.50, 55.50, 55.50, 40.50}; //breakfast prices
```

Then I call for the price like this:

```
int desayuno(); //function for  breakfast submenu
{
    do {
        printf("--------------- Desayunos ---------------\n");
        printf("Por favor, elija la opción deseada con el número del artículo a la izquierda: \n"); //choose an option
        printf("No Descripción                                          Precio");
        printf("1. Omelete al gusto ----------------------------------- $40.50\n");
        printf("2. Huevos al gusto con guacamole ---------------------- $40.50\n");
        printf("3. Plato de fruta de temporada con Queso Cottage ------ $45.50\n");
        printf("4. Molletes con tocino o jamón ------------------------ $55.50\n");
        printf("5. Chilaquiles rojos o verdes, con frijoles y totopos-- $55.50\n");
        printf("6. Sándwich de pierna de pavo con queso panela -------- $40.50\n");
        scanf("%d", &seleccion);
        //Submenu (desayunos)
        switch (seleccion) {

            case 1:
                printf("Omelete al gusto \n");
                printf("Número de ordenes \n"); //How many do you want ?
                scanf("%d", &ordenes);
                suma = ordenes * desayunoa[0]; //this is where I take the price from the array to save it to "cuenta" (bill)
                cuenta = cuenta + suma;
                printf("------------------\n");
                printf("------------------\n");
                printf("------------------\n");
                break;

                       }

        printf("¿Desea agregar algún desayuno más?\n"); //anything else?
        printf("1.Sí\n"); //yes
        printf("2.No\n"); //no
        scanf("%d", &salida);

        if (salida == 1) {
            system("cls"); //clear screen.
            {
                menu();
            }
        }
        else {
            total(); //THIS IS THE FUNCTION I NEED
        }
```

So far I only had total() like this:

```
float total(); // this only prints "cuenta" (bill) which have the total price to pay
                        do {
                            printf("Su total es de: %f", cuenta);
                        }
```

which print the total account. I need the account item by item on the ticket.

Maybe Im doing all wrong I really apreciate if you could take a look to the full code. Thanks in advance.

[full code](http://www.mediafire.com/view/y5ra8955datw8wu/fullcode.txt)

Comment: So you would like to (1)print a list of all ordered meals and their prices to a file, yeah? Like this: Huevos - 40.50, Huevos - 40.50, Omlete - 81.00 (...). (2) give your output file a specific name, yes?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want, the name of the file depend of the time on the machine.

Comment: Take a look at [**C programming begginner issue**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400529/c-programming-begginner-issue?s=2|0.0908). Then when you are ready to print the final invoice, use `fprintf` to write the **text** to a file, and see `asctime` or `ctime` to format the filename with the date.